# how can i find the count of occurrences of multiple dates in my mysql table within a date range in php.

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to count the occurrences of dates which are in a database table `holidays` within a date range `start` and `end`. But somehow i'm getting error. Please help me with this code. Here is my code.

HTML file

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" name="form1" action="occurrences.php">
  From date:<br>
  <input type="date" name="fromdate" id="from">
  <br>
  To date:<br>
  <input type="date" name="todate" id="to">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

occurences.php

```
require('config.php');
$start = isset($_POST['fromdate']) ? $_POST['fromdate']:NULL;
$end = isset($_POST['todate']) ? $_POST['todate']:NULL;
$catch=0;
$statement = mysql_query("SELECT holiday FROM holidays");
$dates=Array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($statement)){

  // add each row returned into an array
  $dates[] = $row;
foreach($dates AS $date) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    if($timestamp >= $start && $timestamp <= $end) {
        $catch++;
    } 
}
}
echo $count;
```

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if this answers your question, but I think you should be using the SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(holiday) FROM holidays WHERE holiday BETWEEN $fromdate AND $todate
```

here $todate and $fromdate have to have the values you get from post and have to be integers.

I hope this helps